# Can 'coredump' folder be deleted safely?

Tags: internal-storage

Internal memory (1.21 GB) of my phone is mainly occupied by a folder named 'coredump' (size ~900 MB). Will it be safe to delete it? What should i do to release this memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short answer

I wouldn't recommend deleting the *folder* itself, but it should be pretty safe to delete its *content* (i.e. the files inside). I'm just afraid you won't be able to do so – unless you have root access on your device.

#### Explanation

[Core dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coredump) (on some Android devices also called "tombstones", which somehow explains their purpose) are generated when an app crashes (or force-closes). They usually contain a complete dump of the memory that app was using, plus some additional information – and are intended *for debugging purposes* (to provide the developer with information about the state the app was in when it crashed – hence "tombstones", describing the "dead of a process").

The system itself doesn't need them at all, so deleting them should be pretty safe. However, depending on implementation, the system might rely on the fact the folder is there – so removing the folder along might have "negative side-effects" (should not, but who knows). As an empty folder is not using up any space, it shouldn't hurt to keep it.

On the other hand: as its only purpose is collecting those "crash reports", and as they probably won't go anywhere either: who cares whether "writing those crash-logs crashes"? ;)